# SBT does not propagate changes in webapp when using xsbt-web-plugin and JRebel

Tags: scala, sbt, lift, jrebel, xsbt-web-plugin

The set up is as follows:

- Lift Web
- xsbt-web-plugin
- sbt-jrebel-plugin
- JRebel

My static web files (html, etc) are in `/src/webapp`

I run

```
# sbt

> jetty:start
> ~compile
```

**Problem:** even thought SBT detects changes in static files, as well as JRebel logs indicating that it also see them, the changes are not propagated into `/target/webapp`. Recompilation and reload of scala files works fine.

build.sbt

```
  organization := "serendipity"

  name := "story-telling"

  version := "1.0"

  scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

  libraryDependencies ++= {
    val liftVersion = "3.0-RC3"
    Seq(
      "net.liftweb" %% "lift-webkit" % liftVersion % "compile",
      "net.liftweb" %% "lift-mapper" % liftVersion % "compile",
      "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.3.13.v20161014",
      "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.193"
    )
  }

  enablePlugins(JettyPlugin)

  seq(jrebelSettings: _*)

  jrebel.webLinks += (sourceDirectory in Compile).value / "webapp"

  jrebel.classpath <<= Seq(Keys.classDirectory in Compile).join

  jrebel.enabled := true

  javaOptions in Jetty ++= Seq(
    "-javaagent:/opt/jrebel/jrebel.jar",
    "-noverify",
    "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC",
    "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled",
    "-Drebel.log=debug",
    "-Drebel.log.file=/home/anton/.jrebel/jrebel.log"
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run instead:

```
> jetty:start
> ~compile
```

as far as i understand this is a workaround rather than the proper solution